# Очень странная ошибка System.ArgumentException: "API-функция вызвана с аргументами из неправильного контекста."

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

Создал проект на WPF и закинул на него пару кнопок и началась магия, по другому я не могу сказать.
Запускаю проект на F5 и пытаюсь развернуть форму - получаю ошибку `System.ArgumentException: "API-функция вызвана с аргументами из неправильного контекста."`
Никаких потоков у меня нет. Проект, можно сказать, чистый, на окне только 2 кнопки и ничего больше.
Если запускать проект на <kbd>Ctrl+f5</kbd> - всё прекрасно работает и ничего не вылетает и не крашится.
С чем это может быть связано?
Использую библиотеки: prism, propertychanged.fody, devexpress.mvvm.

А если еще добавить `DataGrid`, то вылетает сразу после появления окна.

p.s. - если убрать viewmodel, то никаких проблем нет. Но в чем проблема с ней? Там просто инициализация `ObservableCollection` (просто new ...).

Подробности ошибки:

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Сообщение = API-функция вызвана с аргументами из неправильного контекста.
  Источник = PresentationCore
  Трассировка стека:
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaSystem.AssertSameContext(DispatcherObject reference, DispatcherObject other)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.set_VisualTransform(Transform value)
   at System.Windows.Media.ContainerVisual.set_Transform(Transform value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at FoldersWatcher.App.Main()

  Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов: 
    [Внешний код]
```

Разметка окна:

```xml
<Window x:Class="FoldersWatcher.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FoldersWatcher.ViewModels"
        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignWindow}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Folders Watcher" 
        Height="450" 
        Width="800"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MainWindowViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <GroupBox Header="Папки для слежения"
                  Margin="5">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Добавить папку" 
                        Command="{Binding AddFolderCommand}"
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                        Margin="5"/>

                <Button Content="Удалить выбранную папку" 
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                        Margin="5"/>

                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" 
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFolder}"
                         Margin="5"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Файлы"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Margin="5">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Папки для слежения.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<string> Folders { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Файлы, которые были созданы.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<FileModel> Files { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Выбранная папка.
    /// </summary>
    public string SelectedFolder { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Надблюдатели за папками.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Dictionary<string, FileSystemWatcher> watchers;

    /// <summary>
    /// Notification manager.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly INotificationManager notificationManager;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sync.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly TaskFactory sync;

    /// <summary>
    /// Конструктор.
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Конструктор.
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindowViewModel(INotificationManager notificationManager, TaskFactory sync)
    {
        this.notificationManager = notificationManager;
        this.sync = sync;

        Folders = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Files = new ObservableCollection<FileModel>();
        watchers = new Dictionary<string, FileSystemWatcher>();

        AddFolderCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddFolder);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Команда добавления новой папки для слежения.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand AddFolderCommand { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавить папку для слежения.
    /// </summary>
    private void AddFolder()
    {

    }
}
```

App.cs

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// View -> ViewModel.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
    {
        ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<MainWindow, MainWindowViewModel>();

        base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Создание окна.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Регистрация зависимостей.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterDelegate<TaskFactory>(x => new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()), Reuse.Singleton);

        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<INotificationManager, NotificationManager>();
    }
}

static class ContainerHelper
{
    public static void RegisterDelegate<T>(this IContainerRegistry containerRegistry, Func<IResolverContext, T> func, IReuse reuse, string key = null)
    {
        containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterDelegate<T>(func, reuse, serviceKey: key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы так красочно рассказываете про код, но ничего не показали. Код окна, вьюмодели, и xaml разметку в студию.

Comment: Зачем вы одновременно используете prism и другие 2 пакета? Насколько мне известно, первый умеет все что умеют 2 остальных. Быть может у вас конфликт названий классов где-то.

Comment: Нет, есть уже проект со всеми этими пакетами. Всё прекрасно работает. В prism нету некоторых вещей из devexpress.mvvm, а от fody не могу отказаться никак, не охото одинаковый код писать для св-в. Код viewmodel и разметку окна приложил (каюсь, забыл про него).

Comment: так же приложил код App.cs

Comment: Обезглавили код вьюмодели. Не экономьте на буквах, покажите сигнатуру класса, что он там наследует?

Comment: Наследует класс от DevExpress.Mvvm, с ним точно всё нормально (по опыту использования в других проектах). IoC приложил в App.cs

Comment: обновил viewmodel. INotificationManager - пакет из nuget'a "Notification.Wpf" от Platonenkov (но он даже не вызывается нигде, какая с ним может быть проблема?)

Comment: Сейчас удалил первый конструктор с параметрами и засунул инициализацию в первый - всё запустилось без проблем. Но почему? В другом проекте всё было и есть отлично, TaskFactory передается, INotificationManager там тоже есть и отлично работает. А тут - нет.

Comment: Проблема с INotificationManager, если его не запрашивать - всё отлично.

Comment: Нашел ошибку. Сейчас напишу ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка оказалась в пакете Notifications.WPF
Если вы используете его и используете IoC, то регистрировать его нужно примерно так:

```cs
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<INotificationManager>(x => new NotificationManager(App.Current.Dispatcher));
```

Comment: Как то не очень согласуется это: `Создал проект на WPF и закинул на него пару кнопок и началась магия, по другому я не могу сказать.` с проектом в котором, оказывается, установлен `Notifications.WPF` и используется `IoC`. В следующий раз, когда описываете вопрос, не вводите людей в заблуждение ложным описанием проблемы.